# Question about the graph of the square root function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, graphing-functions

I know this question may be stupid but I've been studying for my test tomorrow and I'm so frustrated, I can't figure this one out.
if we have a square root function like this: $y = \sqrt{x}$ wouldn't $y$ be both $+2$ and $-2$ for $x = 4$, so shouldn't the graph look like a quadratic graph?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By convention, $\sqrt x$ doesn't just mean *any* number whose square is $x$ -- it means the *positive* (or zero) number whose square is $x$.

In particular $\sqrt 4$ is $2$ and only that. It is true that $(-2)^2$ is also $4$, but because $-2$ is not positive, it doesn't satisfy the condition for being $\sqrt 4$.

Answer (score 0):

Functions send each $x$ to only one $y$ value. So while it is true that the root of a real number can be positive or negative, in order to graph as a function, the convention is to choose the positive root.

However, you'll notice the inverse of the function $y= {x}^{1/2}$ should also be a parabola, as it is formed by reflecting over the line $y=x,$ but one turned on its side, so your intuition is not far off. Just remember the convention for your exam, and good luck.

Comment: Thanks, I'm wondering why our teacher didn't say anything about this "convention", it's been driving me crazy for the past 2 hours.

Comment: The inverse of $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ is $f^{-1}(x) = x^2, x \geq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

In this case it is so called principal square root, i.e. the nonnegative root of equation $x^2=y$.

See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root.